# Can't lock icon position on Win 10 home edition

Tags: windows-10

Every time I change to a another user account ( I have 2) Win10 rearranges the icons on the screen. I can not lock the Icons in place!
 How can i control the icon placement?

Answer (score -1):

Mike,

Different account won't share the same desktop in Windows, you could only take control one desktop for one user at the same time. 
Basically, Windows would save the Icon where the last time you placed it, and it won't sync with different local accounts on the same machine.

For Microsoft Account, it will only keep sync with defferent devices:

[About sync settings on Windows 10 devices](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/about-sync-settings-on-windows-10-devices)

Comment: Read the question, and then read your answer. Does this answer his question? You are talking about sync, while he is just talking about switching accounts on the same PC. Please try to understand what the questioner is trying to ask before answering. Also, there is no need to address him in your answer.